# Duplicate artboard with script Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard, actions, script

I tried to create an action to automate "duplicate artboard" in Illustrator CC
but it was not possible. I would like to know if there is any script to do this.
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yea the problem is, it's not a recordable action, and while it appears simple on the surface, there's apparently a lot to duplicating an artboard. But, you can augment the code with your needs. This snippet will make a new artboard and use copy/paste to put the items on the new artboard. If the new artboard happens to be off the side of the pasteboard, that's a code edit. If you happen to have 1000 artboards already and adding the next one throws an error or causes a crash, that's a code edit. If you have a problem with how it trashes your existing selection, or clipboard, you better believe that's a code edit!

But here is my simple sample!

```
#target illustrator
function test(){
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var thisBoardIndex = doc.artboards.getActiveArtboardIndex();
    var thisBoard = doc.artboards[thisBoardIndex];
    var thisRect = thisBoard.artboardRect;
    var lastBoard = doc.artboards[doc.artboards.length - 1];
    var lastRect = lastBoard.artboardRect;
    doc.selectObjectsOnActiveArtboard();
    app.copy();
    var newBoard = doc.artboards.add(thisRect);
    var offsetH = 20;
    newBoard.artboardRect = [
        lastRect[2] + offsetH,
        lastRect[1],
        lastRect[2] + offsetH + (thisRect[2] - thisRect[0]),
        lastRect[3]
    ];
    newBoard.name = thisBoard.name + " copy";
    app.executeMenuCommand("pasteFront");
    doc.selection = null;
};
test();
```

Comment: My friend, what you did works perfectly for me. I tried to get the content pasted into a new layer, but it did not work. Do you have a solution for this? If you not have, no problem, you've helped a lot. I added `targetLayer = doc.layers.add();`

Comment: Then you'd have to do a loop and move all of the selection into the new layer, after the pasteFront command runs and before you deselect things. The loop may need to go backwards: for(var i = doc.selection.length - 1; i > -1; i--), and the move command is like this: doc.selection[i].move(targetLayer, ElementPlacement.PLACEATEND);

Comment: @Silly-V Throws the following error when I run the script: `Error 1200: an illustrator error occured.... Line 13: ->  newBoard.artboardRect = [`. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce this error at all. Maybe it's got something to do with the way your document is laid out?

Answer (score -1):

For Coping the layer as crazy as it is that one is a recordable action so you could use that to copy the layer then run the action as a batch on the needed folder.