# Illustrator Action / Script To Do Repetitive Artboard Reduction + Export

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, batch-processing, artboard, illustrator-scripting

So I have a large number of `*.ai` files with assets at 3 unique sizes.

I want to export the right most one to file (the largest one).

My current process for doing this manually is:

1. Open File
2. Delete paths in left two artboards with `V` (Selection Tool) + `(manually select paths)` + `Del`.
3. Enter artboard editor mode: `Document Setup` > `Edit Artboards`.
4. Click 'X' icon in top right of each of the leftmost artboards to delete them.
5. `File` > `Export`
6. Click `Use Artboards` checkbox
7. Click save (default name based upon `*.ai` file name is appropriate in my case).

[image]

Obviously if I had some way to batch or script this manual process, it would be much quicker.

A brief search in local questions yielded an answer on [creating artboards via script](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/105043/duplicate-artboard-with-script-illustrator-cc), but nothing on going in the opposite direction -- deleting them via script.

Also: I should add that the leftmost two artboards (which I'm deleting) are always the same size and position relative the largest artboard.  I imagine that would help on any automated solution, albeit I'm anticipating it'd be complex given the lack of pertinent material I found when poking around.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are doing steps you don't need to do.

- Make an action saving a PDF copy and selecting just the art board 3

[image: artboard3]

[image: Action]

- At the PDF options window, select Illustrator default

[image: Illustrator Default]

- Uncheck **Preserve Illustrator Editing Capabilities**

[image: Preserve Illustrator Editing Capabilities]

- Opening this PDF in Illustrator will only have the art board 3

[image: Art board 3]

After having all the PDFs it will be easier to make an action to save them as PNG from Illustrator or better a Photoshop batch.

Comment: I think the other answer may save me a bit more time, but I also appreciate your contribution as it gives me more options to skin the cat... err no pun intended.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Illustrator Actions, but a little script inserted into your actions via menu item would help make the artboards part work.

```
#target illustrator
 function test(){
   var doc = app.activeDocument;
   doc.artboards[2].remove();
   doc.artboards[1].remove();
};
test();
```

Try this script to see if it removes the right artboards. If they are in a specific order, it will work. Otherwise put numbers 0 & 1 into the square brackets and see if that works!

Comment: I edited it to a proper code block, if that wasn't what you wanted, please feel free to roll it back.

Comment: After testing it, I see that removes the art boards but not its content, the second point in the question.

Comment: For removing the other contents you can try to start with your main item selected, then use "select inverse" and "delete" inside of your action.

Comment: Right, one upside to this approach is that you could potentially with a single selection do:

- Art board remove (using script in answer)
- Path delete (using Silly-V)
- Export w/ artboard considered to PNG

...all in a single composited action.

Compared to the PDF route, seems that would be a quicker route to getting the select artboard contents exported to the form I want (PNG).